# Script - How to disable the cursor?

Tags: scripting, game-engine

How to disable the cursor.
I'm using this script that disables the course view more as I can click the menus even without viewing the cursor.

```
import bge
from bge import render


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    bge.render.showMouse(False)

main()
```

Comment: It's the intended behavior, that only hide the cursor. Rephrase your question, your problem is with your logic of whatever you doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code hides the cursor. Nothing more nothing less. It just contains quite a lot of unnecessary "decoration".

This is the core of the code:

```
import bge
bge.render.showMouse(False)
```

As it says it hides the cursor.

It does not make your game ignore the mouse input. You didn't mentioned how your game deals with mouse input. Therefore you get a very generic answer:

- **let your logic ignore the mouse input**

When you provide more details you might get a more specific answer that fits your current situation.

## Recommendation

> ... the cursor to be disabled to prevent the game from clicking other menu buttons ...

I suggest you disable "clicking". There are many options to do so:

- remove the clickable object (when you need clicking again - add another clickable object)
- add a sensor that indicate if clicking is active or not e.g. via property
  [image]
- switch states to enable/disable clicking
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: Right. There is Logic Bricks which activates the visibility of the course in the same way as this script just changing to True. When the player clicks on new game I need the cursor to be disabled to prevent the game from clicking other menu buttons avoiding bugs ...

Logic Bricks -> Always + Script (this script).

Comment: I added three recommendations

Comment: Interesting. I did not know I could use state and motion to solve this. Thank you very much!